# How to return an array of class type and fill?

Tags: arrays, .net, vb.net, class

I have a function which is supposed to return an array of class type.

So from database I picked data and filled datatable. Now from datatable I am picking columns value and assigning to the properties of the class. But problem is that what I am doing will assign a single record only but I want to fill the class type array with multiple record.

My code:

```
Private Sub BindGridInfoFunctionalLocation()
        Dim v_ObjDs As New DataSet
        Try
            v_ObjDs = v_ObjBREngine.FetchSqlDS("select FunctionalLocation as 'TagNo', EquipmentDescription as 'TagDescription', Area as 'ParentHeirarchy', EqptType as 'TypeClass' from EngineeringData")

            Dim dtTableFL As DataTable
            dtTableFL.Columns.Add("TagNo", GetType(String))
            dtTableFL.Columns.Add("TagDescription", GetType(String))
            dtTableFL.Columns.Add("ParentHeirarchy", GetType(String))
            dtTableFL.Columns.Add("Class", GetType(String))

            dtTableFL = v_ObjDs.Tables(0)

            Dim AssetsCls As New AssetsDto
            'Dim AssetsClsArray As New AssetsDto()

            If v_ObjDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                'v_ObjDs.Tables(0).Rows.Add(v_ObjDs.Tables(0).NewRow())

                For Each Item In dtTableFL.Rows

                    AssetsCls.ASSETTAG = Item("TagNo")
                    AssetsCls.ASSETDESC = Item("TagDescription")
                    AssetsCls.PARENTTAG = Item("ParentHeirarchy")
                    AssetsCls.ASSETTYPE = Item("TypeClass")

                Next

                gv_InfoFunctionalLocation.DataSource = v_ObjDs
                gv_InfoFunctionalLocation.DataBind()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Note:

the return type and everything should be like this since I am interacting with the client's web service and it expects it this way only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example there is no array where each element of the table could be stored after the transform in an AssetsDto. Moreover, you need to change from Sub to Function if you want to return anything to the caller.
Another important change is relative to the data structure used to store the Dtos. Instead of using an array (you need to know the number of elements to effectively use it), I suggest to use a List(Of AssetsDto) where you can dynamically add elements without worrying about the size to the list.

```
' Declare as a Function that returns a List(Of AssetsDto)
Private Function BindGridInfoFunctionalLocation() as List(Of AssetsDto)
    Dim v_ObjDs As New DataSet

    ' This is where we store each record transformed in an AssetsDto
    Dim result as List(Of AssetsDto) = new List(Of AssetsDto)
    Try
        v_ObjDs = v_ObjBREngine.FetchSqlDS("select FunctionalLocation as 'TagNo', EquipmentDescription as 'TagDescription', Area as 'ParentHeirarchy', EqptType as 'TypeClass' from EngineeringData")

        Dim dtTableFL As DataTable = v_ObjDs.Tables(0)

        ' Cycle to create the AssetsDto
        For Each Item In dtTableFL.Rows

            ' IMPORTANT. At each loop create a new AssetsDto, otherwise you
            ' will just change the values of the same instance 
            Dim AssetsCls As AssetsDto = new AssetsDto()
            AssetsCls.ASSETTAG = Item("TagNo")
            AssetsCls.ASSETDESC = Item("TagDescription")
            AssetsCls.PARENTTAG = Item("ParentHeirarchy")
            AssetsCls.ASSETTYPE = Item("TypeClass")

            ' Add the instance to the list
            result.Add(AssetsCls)
        Next
        gv_InfoFunctionalLocation.DataSource = v_ObjDs
        gv_InfoFunctionalLocation.DataBind()
    End If

    ' Return to caller the results
    Return results
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: alright. but the request would be expecting a class type array i.e. AssetsDTO() and responding with List of ASSETSDTO , would not be mismatch?

Comment: _[List.ToArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray?view=netcore-3.1)_ is a built-in methof for any List(Of Type) types. In other words. Fill the list without the complications of an array, then when sending the data to your webservice convert the list to an array

Comment: read my updated question. THe problem is that i am interacting with a web service and my program should be expecting only the AssetsDTO() as a return type.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. My example above fills a List. If you want to return an array then just call _results.ToArray()_ and change the declaration for the return type of the function. I can't see where is the problem.

Comment: wait let me try that

Comment: hi yes, it did. Sorry i couldn't reply. put ur answer in box and i will mark

Comment: maerked as an answer (Y)

Answer (score 0):

This is only an *indirect* answer, but: ultimately, the thing you are trying to do is a solved problem, with lots of tools existing to do *all the work for you*. Since this is a simple scenario, ["Dapper"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) would make this trivial. I'll give a C# example here, as my VB level is read-only:

```cs
List<AssetsDto> BindGridInfoFunctionalLocation()
{
    // note: column aliases to match properties on AssetsDto
    var results = connection.Query<AssetsDto>(@"
select  FunctionalLocation as 'ASSETTAG',
        EquipmentDescription as 'ASSETDESC',
        Area as 'PARENTTAG',
        EqptType as 'ASSETTYPE'
from    EngineeringData").AsList();

    gv_InfoFunctionalLocation.DataSource = results;
    gv_InfoFunctionalLocation.DataBind()
    return results;
}
```